# How to remove 2 characters before a specif string

Tags: c#

I want to remove 2 characters before a specif string from a text.
For eg my text looks like:

```
"/^ApplicationNode1Node2<$ApplicationNode3....."
```

So I want to remove 2 chars before Application

Expected Ouput: "**ApplicationNode1Node2ApplicationNode3**....."

Comment: Add the expected output... "ApplicationNode1Node2ApplicationNode3Node2ApplicationNode9Node5 " ??? Do you want remove or change with a ',' or ';' ??

Comment: Expected Ouput: "ApplicationNode1Node2ApplicationNode3....."

Comment: Great! Always trying to improve the question and not add more comments

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

This method will remove special characters..

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Comment: my string contains multiple Application string.                                          For eg. string book = ""/^ApplicationNode1Node2/^ApplicationNode3Node2+&ApplicationNode9Node5........"

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple Application string`?

Comment: how did you come up with that 2 characters? is that random?

Comment: My complete string will contain multiple Application text. For eg.         String bookname = "/^ApplicationNode1Node2/&ApplicationNode4Node7/*ApplicationNode9Node2";

Comment: why don't you use a constant separtor? like `#`? so that it would be easy to split the string

Comment: your 2 random chars are always special characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

//replace unwanted chars

```
String newString = oldString.Replace("\^","");
```

Or

//read from second character

```
String newString = oldString.SubString(2);
```

Comment: I am not sure about the 2 charcters which I need to remove. It would be diffeent each time. so I cant use...String newString = oldString.Replace("\^","");

Comment: Do you know if it will always be two characters?

Comment: Could the two chars be anything or are there a some finite values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `remove()`

```
data="/^ApplicationNode1Node2<$ApplicationNode3";
data.Remove(0,2);
```

*Let me know if you are looking for something else*

Answer (score 0):

Following code removes any two characters before the string `Application`:

```
var str = "/^ApplicationNode1Node2<$ApplicationNode3.....";
str = Regex.Replace(str, ".{2}Application", "Application");

// result is "ApplicationNode1Node2ApplicationNode3....."
```